# Audio Record and Playback Failing - Android AudioRecord & AudioTrack

Tags: java, android, audio, audiorecord, audiotrack

I am writing an Android Application for Recording and playing back audio in a loop.
Like an echo (Record, Play, run in a loop).

I have successfully written the application for Recording and playing using a temp file, (write into file, read from the same file).
Doing the same using a intermediate buffer is failing.

Here is my code:

```
public class BufferMain extends ActionBarActivity {
private String TAG = "AUDIO_RECORD_PLAYBACK_SAURABH_BUFFER";

private boolean isRunning = false;

private AudioRecord recorder = null;
private AudioTrack track = null;

/* Buffer used to record and Playback Audio */
byte buffer[] = new byte[640];
int bufferSize;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_buffer_main);

    enableButton(R.id.StartButton,true);
    enableButton(R.id.StopButton,false);

    /* Assign Button Click Handlers */
    ((Button)findViewById(R.id.StartButton)).setOnClickListener(btnClick);
    ((Button)findViewById(R.id.StopButton)).setOnClickListener(btnClick);

    Log.d(TAG, "\n ==Starting Application.. ==");
}

/* Method for Recording and Playing in a loop */
public void run_loop (boolean isRunning)
{
    int readbytes, writebytes, state;
    Log.d(TAG, "===== Entering Loop ===== ");

    if (isRunning == true) {
        do {
            bufferSize = 640; /* since configuration would return 640 size in buffer */
            recorder = findAudioRecord(recorder);
            if (recorder == null) {
                Log.e(TAG, "====== findAudioRecord : Returned Error! =======");
                return;
            }

            if (recorder.STATE_INITIALIZED == recorder.getState())
            {
                recorder.startRecording();

                readbytes = 0;              /* Reset read for next Iteration */
                readbytes = recorder.read(buffer, 0, bufferSize);

                /* Error Checking Code for AudioRecord */
                if(-1 == checkAudioRecordforError(readbytes)) 
                {
                    Log.d(TAG, "========= Read Error =========");
                    return;
                }

                Log.d(TAG, "\n\n===== Read : Sizeof Buffer:"+buffer.length+"=== readbytes: ["+readbytes+"]=====");
                recorder.stop();
                recorder.release();

            }else {
                state = recorder.getState();
                Log.d(TAG, "========= Else Part : state : "+state+"=========");
            }

            Log.d(TAG, "========= Reading Completed =========");


            /** ======== API for Playing ===========  **/

            track = findAudioTrack(track);
            if (track == null) {
                Log.e(TAG, "========= findAudioTrack : Returned Error! ========== ");
                return;
            }

            if (track.STATE_INITIALIZED == track.getState()) 
            {
                writebytes = 0;                             /* Reset write bytes for next Iteration */
                track.play();

                writebytes = track.write(buffer, 0, bufferSize);
                Log.d(TAG, "\n\n===== Write : Sizeof Buffer:"+ bufferSize +"==== writebytes: ["+writebytes+"]======== ");

                /* Error Checking Code for AudioRecord */
                if (-1 == checkAudioTrackforError(writebytes)) 
                {
                    Log.d(TAG, "========= Write Error =========");
                    return;
                }

                track.stop();
                track.release();
            }
            else {
                state = track.getState();
                Log.d(TAG, "========= Else Part : state : "+state+"=========");
            }

        } while(true);
    }
    return;
}
/* Method for Initializing   AudioTrack for Playing Purpose */
public AudioTrack findAudioTrack (AudioTrack track)
{
    Log.d(TAG, "========== Initialising Playing API ============");

    bufferSize = AudioTrack.getMinBufferSize(8000, 
            AudioFormat.CHANNEL_OUT_MONO, 
            AudioFormat.ENCODING_PCM_16BIT);        /* Return 640 */

    Log.d(TAG, "========= AudioTrack ==> bufferSize : "+bufferSize+"=========");

    if (bufferSize != AudioTrack.ERROR_BAD_VALUE) 
    {
        track = new AudioTrack(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, 8000, 
                AudioFormat.CHANNEL_OUT_MONO, 
                AudioFormat.ENCODING_PCM_16BIT, bufferSize, 
                AudioTrack.MODE_STREAM);

        if (track.getState() == AudioTrack.STATE_UNINITIALIZED) {
            Log.e(TAG, "=========== AudioTrack UnInitilaised ===========");
            return null;
        }
    }
    return track;
}

/* Method for Initializing AudioRecord for Recording Purpose */
public AudioRecord findAudioRecord (AudioRecord recorder)
{
    Log.d(TAG, "======== Initializing Record API ==========");

    bufferSize = AudioRecord.getMinBufferSize(8000,
            AudioFormat.CHANNEL_IN_MONO,
            AudioFormat.ENCODING_PCM_16BIT);


    if (bufferSize != AudioRecord.ERROR_BAD_VALUE) 
    {
        recorder = new AudioRecord(AudioSource.DEFAULT, 8000, 
                AudioFormat.CHANNEL_IN_MONO,
                AudioFormat.ENCODING_PCM_16BIT, bufferSize);

        if (recorder.getState() == AudioRecord.STATE_UNINITIALIZED) {
            Log.e(TAG, "========= AudioRecord UnInitilaised ============= ");
            return null;
        }
    }
    return recorder;
}

/* Method for Error Checking - AudioRecord */
public int checkAudioRecordforError(int readbytes)
{
    if (readbytes ==  recorder.ERROR_INVALID_OPERATION || readbytes ==  recorder.ERROR_BAD_VALUE) 
    {
        if(readbytes == AudioRecord.ERROR_INVALID_OPERATION)
            Log.d(TAG, "========= read Error : ERROR_INVALID_OPERATION ===========");
        else if (readbytes == AudioRecord.ERROR_BAD_VALUE)
            Log.d(TAG, "========= read Error : ERROR_BAD_VALUE ===========");
        else if (readbytes == AudioRecord.ERROR)
            Log.d(TAG, "========= read Error : ERROR Unknown ===========");
        return -1;
    }
    return readbytes;
}

/* Method for Error Checking - AudioTrack */
public int checkAudioTrackforError(int writebytes)
{
    if (writebytes ==  track.ERROR_INVALID_OPERATION || writebytes ==  track.ERROR_BAD_VALUE)
    {
        if(writebytes == track.ERROR_INVALID_OPERATION)
            Log.d(TAG, "========= read Error : ERROR_INVALID_OPERATION ===========");
        else if (writebytes == track.ERROR_BAD_VALUE)
            Log.d(TAG, "========= read Error : ERROR_BAD_VALUE ===========");
        else if (writebytes == track.ERROR)
            Log.d(TAG, "========= read Error : ERROR Unknown ===========");
        return -1;
    }
    return writebytes;
}

/* Method for Mapping Button Click */
private View.OnClickListener btnClick = new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        switch(v.getId()){
        case R.id.StartButton:
        {
            Log.d(TAG, "======= Start Recording =======");
            isRunning = true;
            Log.d(TAG, "========== isRunning = true =============");
            run_loop (isRunning);
            enableButton(R.id.StartButton,false);
            enableButton(R.id.StopButton,true);
            break;
        }
        case R.id.StopButton:
        {
            Log.d(TAG, "======== Stop Recording =========");
            isRunning = false;
            Log.d(TAG, "========== isRunning = false =============");
            run_loop (isRunning);
            enableButton(R.id.StopButton,false);
            enableButton(R.id.StartButton,true);
            break;
        }
        }
    }
}; 
/* Function to Enable/Disable Buttons */
private void enableButton(int id,boolean isEnable){
    ((Button)findViewById(id)).setEnabled(isEnable);
}
}
```

There is no read write failure anywhere.

Logcat Output:

```
D/AUDIO_RECORD_PLAYBACK_SAURABH_BUFFER( 3885): ==Starting Application.. ==
D/AUDIO_RECORD_PLAYBACK_SAURABH_BUFFER( 3885): ========Start Recording========
D/AUDIO_RECORD_PLAYBACK_SAURABH_BUFFER( 3885): ========== isRunning = true =============
D/AUDIO_RECORD_PLAYBACK_SAURABH_BUFFER( 3885): ===== Entering Loop ===== 
D/AUDIO_RECORD_PLAYBACK_SAURABH_BUFFER( 3885): =========== Initializing Record API =======
E/ACDB-LOADER(  213): Error: ACDB AudProc vol returned = -19
D/AUDIO_RECORD_PLAYBACK_SAURABH_BUFFER( 3885): ===== Read : Sizeof Buffer:640=== readbytes: [640]=====
D/AUDIO_RECORD_PLAYBACK_SAURABH_BUFFER( 3885): ========= Reading Completed =========
D/AUDIO_RECORD_PLAYBACK_SAURABH_BUFFER( 3885): ========== Initializing Playing API     ========
D/AUDIO_RECORD_PLAYBACK_SAURABH_BUFFER( 3885): ========= AudioTrack ==> bufferSize : 640=========
D/AUDIO_RECORD_PLAYBACK_SAURABH_BUFFER( 3885): ===== Write : Sizeof Buffer:640==== writebytes: [640]======== 
D/AUDIO_RECORD_PLAYBACK_SAURABH_BUFFER( 3885): =========Initialising Record API =========
E/ACDB-LOADER(  213): Error: ACDB AudProc vol returned = -19
```

I need to verify if `E/ACDB-LOADER(  213): Error: ACDB AudProc vol returned = -19` is responsible for the same.
The above Audio Configuration is for `Google Nexus 5`. Might fails to initialize on other devices.

The Android GUI contains two buttons `Start` and `Stop`.

Please help me resolve the above Issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The above Issue has been fixed.

The Problem wasn't with :
`E/ACDB-LOADER(  213): Error: ACDB AudProc vol returned = -19`

I have corrected the Code and Updated it in this Answer:
[Audio Recording and Streaming in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25780130/audio-recording-and-streaming-in-android/25781861#25781861)

**Code Changes:**

1. There is no need to Initialize `AudioRecord` and `AudioTrack` Object more than once
   (Must not be part of loop).
2. There shouldn't be any delay in Read and Write.
   Only Read/Write should be running in a Loop.

This way I'm able to Record Audio and Play the same in a loop, using a buffer.