# Audio Recording and Streaming in Android

Tags: android, audio-streaming, audio-recording

I an developing an android app. I want to accomplish below feature.
I will use my phone's built-in mic to record and at the same time i want the recorded audio to be played through either phone's speakers or headphones.
Is it feasible? If yes, please help me in this.

Comment: When you record, Are you recording in a file or a temporary Buffer ?

Answer (score 6):

Here is a simple Recording and Playback application.
Uses Android [**AudioRecord**](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/AudioRecord.html) and [**AudioTrack**](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/AudioTrack.html),

> **Design**:
>
> The recorded audio is written to a buffer and played back from the same buffer, This mechanism runs in a loop (using Android thread) controlled by buttons.

---

Code

```
private String TAG = "AUDIO_RECORD_PLAYBACK";
private boolean isRunning = true;
private Thread m_thread;               /* Thread for running the Loop */

private AudioRecord recorder = null;
private AudioTrack track = null;

int bufferSize = 320;                  /* Buffer for recording data */
byte buffer[] = new byte[bufferSize];

/* Method to Enable/Disable Buttons */
private void enableButton(int id,boolean isEnable){
    ((Button)findViewById(id)).setEnabled(isEnable);
}
```

---

The GUI has two Buttons **START** and **STOP**.
Enable the Button:

```
enableButton(R.id.StartButton,true);
enableButton(R.id.StopButton,false);

/* Assign Button Click Handlers */
((Button)findViewById(R.id.StartButton)).setOnClickListener(btnClick);
((Button)findViewById(R.id.StopButton)).setOnClickListener(btnClick);
```

---

Mapping START and STOP Button for OnClickListener

```
private View.OnClickListener btnClick = new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        switch(v.getId()){
        case R.id.StartButton:
        {
            Log.d(TAG, "======== Start Button Pressed ==========");
            isRunning = true;
            do_loopback(isRunning);
            enableButton(R.id.StartButton,false);
            enableButton(R.id.StopButton,true);
            break;
        }
        case R.id.StopButton:
        {
            Log.d(TAG, "======== Stop Button Pressed ==========");
            isRunning = false;
            do_loopback(isRunning);
            enableButton(R.id.StopButton,false);
            enableButton(R.id.StartButton,true);
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

---

Start the Thread:

```
private void do_loopback(final boolean flag) 
{
    m_thread = new Thread(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            run_loop(flag);
        }
    });
    m_thread.start();
}
```

---

Method for Initializing AudioRecord and AudioTrack:

```
public AudioTrack findAudioTrack (AudioTrack track)
{
    Log.d(TAG, "===== Initializing AudioTrack API ====");
    int m_bufferSize = AudioTrack.getMinBufferSize(8000, 
            AudioFormat.CHANNEL_OUT_MONO, 
            AudioFormat.ENCODING_PCM_16BIT);

    if (m_bufferSize != AudioTrack.ERROR_BAD_VALUE) 
    {
        track = new AudioTrack(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, 8000, 
                AudioFormat.CHANNEL_OUT_MONO, 
                AudioFormat.ENCODING_PCM_16BIT, m_bufferSize, 
                AudioTrack.MODE_STREAM);

        if (track.getState() == AudioTrack.STATE_UNINITIALIZED) {
            Log.e(TAG, "===== AudioTrack Uninitialized =====");
            return null;
        }
    }
    return track;
}

public AudioRecord findAudioRecord (AudioRecord recorder)
{
    Log.d(TAG, "===== Initializing AudioRecord API =====");     
    int m_bufferSize = AudioRecord.getMinBufferSize(8000,
            AudioFormat.CHANNEL_IN_MONO,
            AudioFormat.ENCODING_PCM_16BIT);

    if (m_bufferSize != AudioRecord.ERROR_BAD_VALUE) 
    {
        recorder = new AudioRecord(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC, 8000, 
                AudioFormat.CHANNEL_IN_MONO,
                AudioFormat.ENCODING_PCM_16BIT, m_bufferSize);

        if (recorder.getState() == AudioRecord.STATE_UNINITIALIZED) {
            Log.e(TAG, "====== AudioRecord UnInitilaised ====== ");
            return null;
        }
    }
    return recorder;
}
```

The Values for `findAudioRecord` or `findAudioTrack` can change based on device.
Please refer [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4843739/audiorecord-object-not-initializing?answertab=votes#tab-top) question.

---

Code for Running the loop:

```
public void run_loop (boolean isRunning)
{

    /** == If Stop Button is pressed == **/
    if (isRunning == false) {
        Log.d(TAG, "=====  Stop Button is pressed ===== ");
        
        if (AudioRecord.STATE_INITIALIZED == recorder.getState()){
            recorder.stop();
            recorder.release();
        }
        if (AudioTrack.STATE_INITIALIZED == track.getState()){
            track.stop();
            track.release();
        }
        return;
    }
    

    /** ======= Initialize AudioRecord and AudioTrack ======== **/
    recorder = findAudioRecord(recorder);
    if (recorder == null) {
        Log.e(TAG, "======== findAudioRecord : Returned Error! =========== ");
        return;
    }

    track = findAudioTrack(track);
    if (track == null) {
        Log.e(TAG, "======== findAudioTrack : Returned Error! ========== ");
        return;
    }

    if ((AudioRecord.STATE_INITIALIZED == recorder.getState()) &&
            (AudioTrack.STATE_INITIALIZED == track.getState()))
    {
        recorder.startRecording();
        Log.d(TAG, "========= Recorder Started... =========");
        track.play();
        Log.d(TAG, "========= Track Started... =========");
    } 
    else 
    {
        Log.d(TAG, "==== Initilazation failed for AudioRecord or AudioTrack =====");
        return;
    }

    /** ------------------------------------------------------ **/

    /* Recording and Playing in chunks of 320 bytes */
    bufferSize = 320;
    
    while (isRunning == true) 
    {
        /* Read & Write to the Device */
        recorder.read(buffer, 0, bufferSize);
        track.write(buffer, 0, bufferSize);

    }
    Log.i(TAG, "Loopback exit");
    return;
}
```

---

Please include the following in `AndroidManifest.xml`

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO" >  </uses-permission>
```

This above procedure is also possible by Writing/Reading from a file using the same APIs.
Why use `audioRecord` over `mediaRecorder` - [See here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12780677/android-audiorecord-and-mediarecorder?answertab=votes#tab-top).

The Code is tested (on Google Nexus 5) and working perfectly.

**Note**: Please add some error-checking code for `recorder.read` and `track.write`, in case you fail. Same applies for `findAudioRecord` and `findAudioTrack`.

Answer (score 0):

First create objects in onCreate method, MediaRecorder class object and the path to file where you want to save the recorded data.

```
  String outputFile = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().
  getAbsolutePath() + "/myrecording.3gp";   // Define outputFile outside onCreate method

  MediaRecorder myAudioRecorder = new MediaRecorder(); // Define this outside onCreate method

  myAudioRecorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC);
  myAudioRecorder.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.THREE_GPP);
  myAudioRecorder.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.AMR_NB);
  myAudioRecorder.setOutputFile(outputFile);
```

These three function you can call it on any button, in order to play Rec, stop Rec and start Rec;

```
  public void start(View view){
  try {
     myAudioRecorder.prepare();
     myAudioRecorder.start();
   } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
     // TODO Auto-generated catch block
     e.printStackTrace();
   } catch (IOException e) {
     // TODO Auto-generated catch block
     e.printStackTrace();
   }
   start.setEnabled(false);
   stop.setEnabled(true);
   Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Recording started", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
  }

  public void stop(View view){

    myAudioRecorder.stop();
    myAudioRecorder.release();
    myAudioRecorder  = null;
    stop.setEnabled(false);
    play.setEnabled(true);
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Audio recorded successfully",
    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
   }



  public void play(View view) throws IllegalArgumentException,   

    SecurityException, IllegalStateException, IOException{
    MediaPlayer m = new MediaPlayer();
    m.setDataSource(outputFile);
    m.prepare();
    m.start();
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Playing audio", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

As I read Developer document [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/appendix/media-formats.html) , Android supports RTSP protocol (for real time streaming) and also HTTP/HTTPS live streaming draft protocol.

There is also an example [here](http://www.androidhive.info/2014/06/android-streaming-live-camera-video-to-web-page/). You must have base knowledge about Streaming server, like Red5 or Wowza.